# How I keep the change of variable only on variable and then update the container latter

Tags: data-binding, containers

1. I made data model and init with problem list

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Question: Identifiable {
    var  id : String =     ""
    var main: String = ""
    var q: [Q] = []
    var answer: [String] = []
    var choice:[String] = []
    var solved: Int = 0
  init( id: String, year: String, intro: String, main: String, q:[Q] , answer:[String], choice: [String], solved: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.main = main
        self.q = q
        self.answer = answer
        self.choice = choice
        self.solved = solved
      }
   }

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@MainActor

let appContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Question.self)
        
        container.
        var itemFetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Question>()
        itemFetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1
        
        guard try container.mainContext.fetch(itemFetchDescriptor).count == 0 else { return container }
      
  Set<Question> = [
            Question(id: "230133", main: "8year old.. , q:  [ Q(id:"1", q: "1.적응장애"),  Q( id:"2", q: "2. 지적장애"),  Q(id:"3", q: "3.반응애착장애"), Q( id:"4",  q: "4.분리불안장애"), Q( id: "5", q: "5.사회의사소통장애")], answer: ["5"] , choice: [], solved: 0, ),
            Question(id: "230136",  intro: "23 year old ..., q: [ Q(id: "1", q: "1.제거장애"), Q( id:"2",  q: "2.폭식장애"), Q(id: "3", q: "3.신경성폭식증"), Q(id: "4", q: "4.제한형 신경성 식욕부진증"), Q(id: "5", q: "5.폭식/제거형 신경성 식욕부진증")] , answer: ["5"], choice: [], solved: 0,  )]

       for item in items {       
            container.mainContext.insert(item)          
        }
        
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container")
    }
}()

@main
struct PsyKMA2024: App {
        var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
       } .modelContainer(appContainer)
      
    }
      
}
```

2. I made a view to choose the problem list which is 0 which mean  "not solve" (1 mean correvt,  2 mean not correct) and  made a view  to take multiple choice exam with thesr items (at first all items are not solved because initialized 0)

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct QuestionView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var dbContext
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @Query(sort:  [SortDescriptor(\Question.id, order: .reverse)])
    @ObservationIgnored private var listProblems: [Question]
    @State private var searchTerm: String = ""
    @State var selectedQuestions : [Question]  = []
    @State var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
  @State private var selectedValueForState: Int = 0
    
var body: some View {  
    let selectedQuestions = listProblems.filter {
           selectedValueForState == 0 ? true : $0.solved == selectedState
           }
   NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility, sidebar: {
            InspectorView( selectedValueForState: $selectedValueForState, visibility: $visibility )   
        }, content:{
            SelectedProblemView(allQuestions: allQuestions, visibility: $visibility)
          }, detail: { 
        TakeExamView(allQuestions: allQuestions)  }
           } 
}
```

3 Here is the selectedProblemView and QuestionBookView for the content part of navigationsplitview

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectedProblemView: View {
     var allQuestions: [Question] = []
    @Binding var examOrResult : Bool
    @Binding var visibility : NavigationSplitViewVisibility
    
    var body: some View {
           List(allQuestions){ question in
            QuestionBook(question: question)
        }
}
}

import SwiftUI

struct QuestionBook: View {
   let question: Question
    
    var body: some View {
        let isCorrect =  !question.choice.isEmpty &&  question.choice == question.answer
       let isNotYet = question.choice.isEmpty
       HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image(systemName:
                    isNotYet ?     "questionmark.circle.fill" :  ( isCorrect ?  "checkmark.circle.fill" :    "xmark.circle.fill" )) .symbolRenderingMode(.
        }
    }
    }
```

4. for detail part of NavigationSplitView I made a TakeExamView and individualView . Here in TakeExamView which shows multiple choice through IndividualView I selected choices then pushed Select button to submit an answer then the item disappeared from detail and content view of the navigation split view.  I want to know How I keep the item selected remain on the detail and content view and allQuestions variable to analyse the total number of correct and wrong answers et al. then I would like to update the container. I guess the selection of answers reflected immediately in the variable and refreshed container through allQuestions variable and the view refreshed.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TakeExamView:  View {
   @ObservationIgnored    var allQuestions : [Question] = []
 var body: some View {
    VStack{
            List(allQuestions) { question in
                IndividualExamView(question: question) 
                            } 
        }
       }
}
      

import SwiftUI

struct IndividualExamView: View, Equatable { 
    @State var question: Question //변경 하지 마시오
    @State var selectedRows   = Set<Q.ID>()
    @State private var buttonDisabled  = false
    
    var body: 
    some View {
        @State var answerBranch = question.q.sorted()
        Text("\(question.main)")
        ForEach(answerBranch) { item in 
            HStack {    
                Text(item.q)
                
                Image(systemName: selectedRows.contains(item.id) ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")}
            .onTapGesture {
                if selectedRows.contains(item.id){
                    selectedRows.remove(item.id)
                } else {
                    selectedRows.insert(item.id)
                }
                
            }
        } 
        
        VStack {
            Button("Answer") {  
                let selected  = selectedRows.sorted()
                let isCorrect = selected == question.answer
                question.choice = selected
                question.solved  =  isCorrect ? 1 : 2
                buttonDisabled =  selectedRows.isEmpty ? false : true
            }
        }
}
```